# Generic types with an extends clause doesn't always get narrowed down like they should

Tags: typescript, generics

In this example:

```
type MyType = 'val1' | 'val2' | 'val3';

const variable = 'val1' as MyType;

const val2 = 'val2';
const val3 = 'val3';

declare function test<U extends MyType>(...args: U[]): void;

test(val2, val3); // U successfully resolves to "val3" | "val2"

declare function test2<T, U extends T>(value: T | undefined, ...values: U[]): void;

test2(variable, val2, val3); // U gets widened to "val1" | "val2" | "val3"
```

In both `test` and `test2`, `U extends MyType`.

Then I expect `test2` to resolve `U` to `"val3" | "val2"` just like it did in `test`, but it doesn't.

Why is that?

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=75&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oHIBuBDANgRjSgB91scAmQkzXAZjQFgAoZgYwHsA7AZ2CmwBOASywAjHClK4CULN1gIkAbmZsuvfrnJRUNCmhVMOPPmVo6pOeoeYATCKxxYB0AGYBXTq2BCuUYBC8ADwAqlAQAB4BnLbycIiQAHwAFAB06c4A5twAXFAhANoAugCUeRjsQrY2TAG8yWTkADSaViVKUAD0nflQ3O6srIHcHjg4IFAu3Ow4GIH%207FAARGZLxMuNS6pM9o7Obp7evpz%20gcDkQfAtYZHRsVDwKWTuEHnw6572rkKcELYt6VSz0CeUKpXKlWq2zq5wazhE4ggLUayLo7S6PTCmQgwHkAHcqhBfrYFhtpGsSCstBSyVYlkA)

Comment: `T` is `MyType` and `U` extends `T` then `U` extends `MyType`.

Comment: `U` extends `MyType` in both cases then why it behaves differently?

Comment: @GuerricP in test1, `val2` is of the type `"val2"` & `val3`  is of the type `"val3"`. While in test2, `variable` is of the type `"val1" | "val2" | "val3"`. So in test1 the type `U` is able to be narrowed down thanks to the types of `val2` & `val3`. However in test2 the type of `T` (and by proxy also `U`) is forced to be as wide as the type of `variable` which is `"val1" | "val2" | "val3"`

Comment: @Olian04 *However in `test2` the type of `T` is forced to be as wide as the type of variable* well it shouldn't since the constraint is `U extends T` so it U could be a sub-type. `'val1' | 'val2'` actually extends `'val1' | 'val2' | 'val3'`

Comment: @GuerricP yes, in a void it could be a subtype. However at the call-site `test2(variable, val2, val3)` we tell typescript that the type of `T` should equal the type of `variable`. In essence `type T = typeof variable`.

Comment: What differs between `test` and `test2` then?

Comment: @GuerricP you know what. Scratch that. I thought I understood the interactions, but while writing a playground example I ended up disproving my theory... in a way. If you change the return type of `test2` from `void` to `U`, then it successfully resolves to `"val3" | "val2"`

Comment: Interesting... that sounds like a bug isn't it?

Comment: @GuerricP likely not. In my experience TS does this kind of thing quite often. The TS team allows TS to cut corners every now and then. Especially if it can detect that the resulting type wont be used elsewhere in the type system. I think TS recons that the type `"val1" | "val2" | "val3"` is good enough for the arguments list. However if the type `U` is expected to be returned, then more time is needed to be spent on resolving its actual type.

Comment: Makes sense. Do you feel like writing an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a case of the type system cutting corners. Typescript is allowed to cut corners on the type checking every now and then. Especially if it can detect that the resulting type won't be used elsewhere in the type system. I think typescript recons that the type `"val1" | "val2" | "val3"` is good enough for the arguments list.
However lets say that we change the return type of `test2` from `void` to `U`. Then, since the type `U` is expected to be returned and possibly used elsewhere in typescript, the compiler will need to dedicate more time to resolving the actual/most narrow type of `U`.

```
type MyType = 'val1' | 'val2' | 'val3';

const variable = 'val1' as MyType;

const val2 = 'val2';
const val3 = 'val3';

declare function test2<T, U extends T>(value: T | undefined, ...values: U[]): void;

test2(variable, val2, val3); // U gets widened to "val1" | "val2" | "val3"

declare function test3<T, U extends T>(value: T | undefined, ...values: U[]): U;

test3(variable, val2, val3); // U successfully resolves to "val3" | "val2"
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oHIBuBDANgRjSgB91scAmQkzXAZjQG4AoJgYwHsA7AZ2CmwBOASywAjHClK4CULN1gIkzNl179c5KKhoVGKnnzK0tUnPWUATCKxxYB0AGYBXTq2BCuUYBF7kAPPAANFAAqlAQAB7enBby8AB8ABRkThAAXFDwxFAuVg5CnBAWwQB0ZSk+GSEA2gC6AJQZGOxCFsrevsl2IuIQwWTk-XT1DFAA9GOhJgBEZHjT2bMaCyRLZtMsVjZ2ji5uHpxePsC0AcFhkdGxmUkVGVkkuRD5hcVQZSUV3FV1jaHtx1oXWEYgkQwo4NoI3GkzCqDWtBWUDW5GmQA)